# running ctakes with the AggregatePlaintextProcessor

Tags: ctakes

I want to run ctakes with the AggregatePlaintextProcessor or something that doesn't require a connection for UMLS. Help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm just getting started with cTAKES and had a similar question when i first installed it.

From your cTAKES home directory run this:

```
bin\runctakesCVD.bat  desc\ctakes-clinical-pipeline\desc\analysis_engine\AggregatePlaintextProcessor.xml
```

instead of this:

```
bin\runctakesCVD.bat  desc\ctakes-clinical-pipeline\desc\analysis_engine\AggregatePlaintextFastUMLSProcessor.xml
```

Basically, you are just removing "FastUMLS" from the command.

More info can be found in the user install guide:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/CTAKES/cTAKES+4.0+User+Install+Guide